# How to mock a successful response in cypress, only when the endpoint return is 503?

Tags: cypress

I would like to wait for an endpoint to respond, if the answer is 200 I would like to continue the test using the body returned from the endpoint, but if the return is a 503 for example, I would like to mock the answer with a 200 and use the body mock, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Cypress version 6 or greater you can use cy.intercept()

You could listen for an endpoint and stub the status code.

Here is an example using the pokemon api. This will stub the response to always send a status of 200 but keep the original response body.

```
it("should stub the status code", () => {
    cy.intercept("GET", "pokemon/4", (req) => {
      req.reply((res) => {
        res.send(200, res.body);
      });
    }).as("charmander");

    cy.visit("https://pokeapi.co/");
    cy.get("#url-input").clear().type("pokemon/4");
    cy.contains("Submit").click();

    cy.wait("@charmander").then((res) => {
      //the stubbed response
      console.log(res);
    });
  });
```

See the cypress docs for further details https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html